# Using Javascript to control innertext of table cells

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
<table id="timbercamptable">
    <tr>
        <th>Production</th>
        <th class="unitspertitle"></th>
        <th class="unitspernexttile"></th>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Base production</td>
        <td class="currentunits"></td>
        <td class="nextunits"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The classes and structure of the tables are the same, but the table id's are different. I wish to control the `innerText` of the classes using JavaScript. What would be the correct way to call these classes, knowing that the other table would have the id `sulphurpittable` and `goldminetable`.

For example I want to change the `innerText` of `currentunits` located in the `timbercamptable`

Comment: do you mean that you want to change the textContent (please don't call it innerText) of the `td` elements with those classes?

Comment: @Touffy what is the mistake in calling it innerText?

Comment: well, it's not an error, just non-standard until quite recently (so Firefox didn't implement it until version 45). [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) has better support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to query for table based on `table id` and `class` of the table cell.

```js
document.querySelector("#timbercamptable .currentunits").textContent = "100.00";
```

```html
<table id="timbercamptable">
    <tr>
        <th>Production</th>
        <th class="unitspertitle"></th>
        <th class="unitspernexttile"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Base production</td>
        <td class="currentunits"></td>
        <td class="nextunits"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I need, I will read up more on `querySelector`